# Appcelerator AdMob doesn't work in TestFlight version

Tags: admob, testflight, appcelerator-titanium

I have a problem with AdMob only when I run the app on my device (also from test flight).

And error is this: **Failed to receive ad.**

It is working fine on the simulator.

```
var adMob = _admob.createView({
        height: "10%",
        bottom: 0,
        debugEnabled: false, // If enabled, a dummy value for `adUnitId` will be used to test
        adType: _admob.AD_TYPE_BANNER,
        adUnitId: '<MyUnitId>', // You can get your own at http: //www.admob.com/ C: pub-6184325311578061, GG:pub-2569934957549104
        adBackgroundColor: 'black',
        testDevices: [<my device udid>],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `testDevices: [<my device udid>]`.

From [Targeting - Test ads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/targeting):

> Be sure to remove the code that sets these test device IDs before you
>   release your app.

Comment: It is still showing black panel after removing testDevices: [<my device udid>]